# Create object ( var name: [NSArray] ) from list of words

Tags: arrays, swift, object, append, swift4

I have a plain test list of words e.g:

Aardvark
Bear
Cat
Dog
Elephant
Giraffe

I want to turn this into an object with the format:

```
var array: [NSArray]  = [["Aardvark", false, 0], ["Bear", false, 1],["Cat", false, 2], ["Dog", false, 3], ["Elephant", false, 4], ["Giraffe", false, 5]]
```

So the first element is always the word from the list, the second element is always false, and the third element is always the index

How do I do this?

Comment: You should design a proper data model for this. Don't rely on array of arrays

Comment: And `[NSArray]` is a particularly horrible type for this problem. It's both type-unsafe and extremely hard to work with. You want to create a `struct` here and make an array of that. Then this becomes much simpler to create and to use. If you can describe the problem you're solving, I believe we can show you how to create the struct. What's "false" in this case?

Comment: Ah okay. "False" is whether the item in the list has been selected or not.  

False = not selected, so all are false to begin with
True = selected (when the user selects the tableview cell)

Comment: Aardvark Bear Cat Dog Elephant Giraffe

Do you have this value in a string?

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this, slightly different from [Josh Robbins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49071497/4173593) answer.

```
struct TestInfo {
   var name :  String
   var trueOrFalse : Bool
   var index : Int
}
```

.

```
var array: [TestInfo]  = []
    var animalNames = ["Dog","Cat","Bear","Aatdvark","Duck","Elephant"]
    for (index,eachAnimal) in animalNames.enumerated() {
        let element = TestInfo(name: eachAnimal, trueOrFalse: false, index: index)
        array.append(element)
    }
     print(array)
```

Comment: A much cleaner approach :) Although I was just showing how to get started :)

Answer (score 0):

You could store your data in a `struct` e.g:

```
/// Test Elements
struct TestInfo {

var animalName: String
var trueOrFalse: Bool
var index: Int

}
```

In your ViewController, you would then create an array to store these:

```
  //Array To Store The Test Elements
  var testArray = [TestInfo]()
```

And thus could populate your data like so:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()

    //1. Create The Test Info
    let setOne = TestInfo(animalName: "Aardvark", trueOrFalse: false, index: 0)
    let setTwo = TestInfo(animalName: "Bear", trueOrFalse: false, index: 1)
    let setThree = TestInfo(animalName: "Cat", trueOrFalse: false, index: 2)
    let setFour = TestInfo(animalName: "Dog", trueOrFalse: false, index: 3)
    let setFive = TestInfo(animalName: "Elephant", trueOrFalse: false, index: 4)
    let setSix = TestInfo(animalName: "Giraffe", trueOrFalse: false, index: 5)

    //2. Add It To The Test Array
    testArray.append(setOne)
    testArray.append(setTwo)
    testArray.append(setThree)
    testArray.append(setFour)
    testArray.append(setFive)
    testArray.append(setSix)

    //3. Retrieve Values & Log The Results
    let name = testArray[0].animalName
    let trueOrFalse = testArray[0].trueOrFalse
    let index = testArray[0].index

    print("""
        1st Animal Name = \(name)
        1st Animal True Or False Value = \(trueOrFalse)
        1st Animal Index = \(index)
        """)
}
```

This should get you started...

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in your structure seem to correspond with the array index which probably makes them redundant. And storing the selected state this close to the actual data might not be the right way—the array of names is your data while the selected state is part of the presentation of this data.

For this reason you might consider reducing your array to a simple array of strings and adding a set of indexes like this:

```
var selectedItems = Set<Int>()
```

To select an item you would simply add its index to the set:

```
selectedItems.insert(index)
```

To deselect the item you would remove its index from the set:

```
selectedItems.remove(index)
```

A set is a good choice here as you cannot add an item more than once.